# GIMP editor, how to set selection and trim image for production?

Tags: gimp, images, print-production, scanning, image-processing

Using GIMP editor for Microsoft Windows. I have scanned an image and need to  prepare the file for printing and the print file size/dimensions should be 88.5 x 57 mm: How can I set a rectangular selection to these dimensions and trim the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Convert your physical size to pixels using your target resolution.
2. In the options of the *Rectangle Select* tool, check *Fixed* select *Size* and enter the result from the previous step:

   [image: Options of the Rectangle Select tool]
3. Click on the actual document to position your selection as desired.
4. *Image → Crop to Selection.*

If you do not have your target resolution, you can fix the aspect ratio in step 2 instead.